# How do I take inputs through HTML and then use those to run a loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to write a code which will calculate compound interest earned on an investment and after each year (i) ends, it will ask the user if they would like to continue staying invested or if they would like to cash out.

I have been able to write a for loop for calculating final payment after 10 years. However, I can't seem to figure out how to break the loop after each year ends and then ask the user a simple yes or no question about their investment preference. This is the code I input to calculate interest:

```
let userInput = false;
let principal = 100000;
let rate = 0.05;
let amount;

for(let year = 1; year <= 10; ++year)
{
if(userInput) {
    amount = principal * Math.pow(1.0 + rate, year);
    console.log(year);
    console.log(amount.toFixed(2));
}
else {
    {break;}
}
}
```

I am guessing I'll need to create a form with HTML as well, to get the input but not sure how to then take that input and add it into my java code.

I calculated compound interest but can't seem to break the loop and ask the user for go ahead after each year ends.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution without HTML (open your console log to view the output for each year):

```
function calculateInterest(principal, rate, time) {
  let amount = principal * Math.pow(1 + (rate/100), time);
  let interest = amount - principal;
  return interest;
}

let principal = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the initial investment amount:"));
let rate = parseFloat(prompt("Enter the interest rate (% per year):"));
let time = 10;
let invested = true;

for (let i = 1; i <= time; i++) {
  if (!invested) {
    break;
  }
  let interest = calculateInterest(principal, rate, i);
  console.log(`Year ${i}: $${interest + principal}`);
  if (i < time) {
    let decision = prompt("Do you want to continue staying invested? (Enter 'yes' or 'no'):");
    if (decision === "no") {
      invested = false;
      console.log("You have chosen to cash out. Your final investment amount is $" + (interest + principal));
    }
  }
}
if (invested) {
  console.log("You have stayed invested for 10 years. Your final investment amount is $" + (principal * Math.pow(1 + (rate/100), time)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an HTML and JavaScript solution:

```js
function calculateInterest(principal, rate, time) {
  let amount = principal * Math.pow(1 + (rate/100), time);
  let interest = amount - principal;
  return interest;
}

function calculateAndDisplay() {
  let principal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("principal").value);
  let rate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("rate").value);
  let time = 10;
  let invested = true;

  for (let i = 1; i <= time; i++) {
    if (!invested) {
      break;
    }
    let interest = calculateInterest(principal, rate, i);
    console.log(`Year ${i}: $${interest + principal}`);
    if (i < time) {
      let decision = prompt(`Year ${i} is up. Do you want to continue staying invested or cash out? Type 'continue' to stay invested or 'cash out' to end investment.`);
      if (decision === "cash out") {
        invested = false;
        console.log("You have chosen to cash out. Your final investment amount is $" + (interest + principal));
        }
      }
    }
    if (invested) {
      console.log("You have stayed invested for 10 years. Your final investment amount is $" + (principal * Math.pow(1 + (rate/100), time)));
    }
 }
```

```html
<label for="principal">Enter the initial investment amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="principal"><br><br>
<label for="rate">Enter the interest rate (% per year):</label>
<input type="text" id="rate"><br><br>
<button onclick="calculateAndDisplay()">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in multiple ways, of which I'll demonstrate some, in simplified examples.

You can **use promises** (and `async`/`await`) to keep using a `for`-loop:

```js
const divOptions = document.getElementById("investment-options");
const buttonStayIn = document.getElementById("stay-in");
const buttonCashOut = document.getElementById("cash-out");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

invest();

async function invest() {
  let year = 0;
  for (; year < 10 && await getAnswer() === "Stay in"; ++year) {
    // TODO: Calculate
    output.textContent = `Year ${year + 1}`;
  }
  
  divOptions.style.display = "none";
  output.textContent = `You cashed out after ${year} year(s).`;
}

function getAnswer() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Use handlers for one(!) answer; resolve accordingly
  
    let stayInHandler, cashOutHandler;
    const removeListeners = function() {
      buttonStayIn.removeEventListener("click", stayInHandler);
      buttonCashOut.removeEventListener("click", cashOutHandler);
    };
    
    stayInHandler = () => {
      removeListeners();
      resolve("Stay in");
    };
    cashOutHandler = () => {
      removeListeners();
      resolve("Cash out");
    };
    
    buttonStayIn.addEventListener("click", stayInHandler, false);
    buttonCashOut.addEventListener("click", cashOutHandler, false);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="investment-options">
  <button id="stay-in">Stay invested</button>
  <button id="cash-out">Cash out</button>
</div>

<output>Year 0</output>
```

Or –instead of a `for`-loop– you can **manually iterate** per each "staying invested" click:

```js
const divOptions = document.getElementById("investment-options");
const buttonStayIn = document.getElementById("stay-in");
const buttonCashOut = document.getElementById("cash-out");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

let year = 0;

buttonStayIn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextYear();
  
  if (year >= 10) {
    stopInvestment();
  }
});
buttonCashOut.addEventListener("click", stopInvestment);

function nextYear() {
  // TODO: Calculate
  ++year;
  output.textContent = `Year ${year}`;
}

function stopInvestment() {
  divOptions.style.display = "none";
  output.textContent = `You stopped your investment after ${year} year(s).`;
}
```

```html
<div id="investment-options">
  <button id="stay-in">Stay invested</button>
  <button id="cash-out">Cash out</button>
</div>

<output>Year 0</output>
```

Or you can **use user prompts** ([similar to this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75277283/13561410)) since they halt the site (and therefore the script) until they return:

```js
const output = document.querySelector("output");

let year = 0;

for (; year < 10 && confirm(`Stay in? Current year: ${year}`); ++year) {
  // TODO: Calculate
  output.textContent = `Year ${year}`;
}

output.textContent = `You stopped your investment after ${year} year(s).`;
```

```html
<output>Year 0</output>
```

**Sidenote**: User prompts (such as `alert()`, `prompt()` and `confirm()`) usually halt a site. This means the site will be unresponsive, and even animations will stop for the prompt's duration, resulting in bad UX.

Alternatively, you can just **ask ahead of time** (if possible) how many years they would like to invest:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

form.addEventListener("submit", evt => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  const years = form.years.valueAsNumber;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < years; ++i) {
    // TODO: Calculate
  }
  
  form.style.display = "none";
  output.textContent = `You cashed out after ${years} year(s).`;
});
```

```html
<form id="f-investment">
  <label for="i-years">
    Invest for years:
    <input id="i-years" name="years" type=number value=0 min=0 max=10>
  </label>
  <button>Invest</button>
</form>

<output for="f-investment"></output>
```

---

Personally, I would consider the following a malformed `for`-loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  if (bool) {
    // ...
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Because it can easily be rewritten as:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10 && bool; ++i) {
  // ...
}
```